# FLASK The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: python, html, flask

How to resolve this error message?

This is my first time create app and use FLASK

When I upload a image in index, I will got the error message:Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

I checked filename, and put index.html in "\templates" , .py put in \htdocs\templates or \templates

```
index.html
<form action="{{url_for('predict')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Predict">
    <div id ="result">
        <strong style="color:red">{{ result }}</strong>
```

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict', methods =['POST'])
def predict():
    image = request.files['image']
    return render_template('index.html', result = 'test')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

if need more code,please tell me.